# How to save Gridview cell data in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

My Gridview seems like this:

[image]

This has `TimeSlotID` as **Datakey**.

This is a timetable gridview data.I want to store this in database.

Table rows:

> Timetable_ID
>     SlotID
>     Subject_Faculty
>     TimeslotNumber
>     Semester
>     WeekDay

`SlotID` means StartTime and EndTime `SlotID(StartTime and Endtime are being fetched from another database table)`

`TimeSlotNumber` means the Current Row (example: TimeslotNumber value for 8:50-9:10 is **2**). `Timetable_ID` and `Semester` will be fetched from above dropdownlists.

My question is how to store my gridview data into Database

Referred Link:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/10923/insert-data-into-database-from-gridview-in-Asp-Net.aspx

But no help as it saves row wise data. I need to store it as blockwise (Means row+column). But gridview doesn't have property like GridviewColumn.

```
  GridView3.DataSource = dt2; //dt2 is for timeslots and datakey[SlotID]
  GridView3.DataBind();
  GridView3.Columns[2].Visible = false;
  GridView3.Columns[3].Visible = false;
  GridView3.Columns[4].Visible = false;
  GridView3.Columns[5].Visible = false;
  GridView3.Columns[6].Visible = false;
  GridView3.Columns[7].Visible = false;
    count = 1;
    int branchID = ob.getBranchID(Convert.ToInt16(ddlschema.SelectedValue.ToString()));

    DataTable dtsub = ob.getFacultySubject(branchID,Convert.ToInt16(DropDownList29.SelectedValue.ToString()));

    dtsub.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string), "Fname + ' ' + Lname + '--' + SubjectName ");

    int temp22=0;
    for (int gv3t1 = 0; gv3t1 < 6; gv3t1++)
    {
        if (weekday[gv3t1] == 1)
        {
            GridView3.Columns[gv3t1 + 2].Visible = true;
            string name = "ddl" + gv3t1;
            ddl[temp22] = name;
            foreach (GridViewRow grdRow in GridView3.Rows)
            {

                bind_dropdownlist = (DropDownList)(GridView3.Rows[grdRow.RowIndex].Cells[gv3t1 + 2].FindControl(name));
                bind_dropdownlist.DataTextField = "Name";
                bind_dropdownlist.DataValueField = "ID";
                bind_dropdownlist.DataSource = dtsub;
                bind_dropdownlist.DataBind();

            }

            temp22++;
         }
      }
```

Comment: Could you paste the code of you method who saves? From there it will be easier to help you.

Comment: i have mentioned a reference link,am following him.Still it would be better if u specify which part of code should I present here as a lot of redirection of methods are there in my project.For example:the data binding method?or data collection method? or save gridview to database?

Comment: Start with the save to database. Where there is your problem. And if you have an error message show it

Comment: Actually sir,,thats my problem,,how to bind data,,but here is the way that how i bind data in gridview..,maybe this helps u

Comment: Sir,i have seen that gridview to database process uses this:foreach (GridViewRow  g1 in Gvrecords.Rows )
                {
                    string id = (g1.FindControl("lblId") as Label).Text;
                    string name = (g1.FindControl("lblName") as Label).Text;
                    string price = (g1.FindControl("lblPrice") as Label).Text;
                    string description = (g1.FindControl("lblDescription") as Label).Text;
                    
                    string query = "insert into product values(" +id+ ",'" + name + "'," +price+ ",'" + description + "')";

Comment: Yes you can iterate the gridView on each row, and retrive the data as you want then use a Sqlcommand object with your query and connection to execute your query. Use parametrized query